# Which Protocol is best for File Transfer

Tags: network-protocols, file-transfer

What is the best protocol I can use to transfer a big file, which should be fast and reliable?
It must support low bandwidth systems since I need a file transmission across India. The file size may be 100 to 500MB.

Comment: You should provide more context for this question.  How big is the file?  Are you transferring the file over a LAN, a high bandwidth WAN, a low bandwidth internet connection?

Comment: And also relevant in context: please specify low bandwidth; are 9600bps; packets per sms or <1Mbps? What is the reliability of your connection? Is the connection likely to drop out? How many peers (or just 1-to-1 connections)?

Comment: I've retagged it; Balamurgan: if there is a relevancy for C# please edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Have a look at this http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2014/02/best-file-transfer-protocol-which-to.html

Answer (score 11):

Rsync is a great fit for this problem. It's designed to send/update big files remotely.

- Runs from the command-line so you can launch it fairly easily as an external process.
- It can synchronize two remote file systems.
- It handles **large file sizes**.
- It has a clever algorithm that seeks to **only copy differences** in files around.
- It's widely implemented and is **open source**.
- It has a **throttling capability** so you can limit how much of a WAN connection you're using up with the transfer so you can tune it to avoid starving other processes of connectivity.
- internally **uses zlib to compress** transferred data blocks

original site: http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/

securing rsync with ssh: http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/113847

detailed features: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync

Answer (score 9):

[File Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol)

[BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29)

> BitTorrent is a peer-to-peer file
>   sharing protocol used for distributing
>   large amounts of data.

[List of file transfer protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_transfer_protocols)

Answer (score 4):

Even though FTP is the most efficient protocol for file transfer, it's pretty hard to implement. I would use HTTP. The support is built-in on most platforms and it's more resilient to firewalls.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to implement the protocol yourself, just use some existing library.

Comment: vsftpd would be the easiest option. Can be installed through apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is probably the way to go for small files and/or unsophisticated users. Having to configure a firewall will stop many users cold. Almost every network allows http transfers over port 80 with no special configuration.

You did say Big files, though. You can write the transfer code such that it uses range transfers to retry interrupted downloads.

Someone has probably written a file transfer library that handles partial transfers and retries automatically, though I don't know of one.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some interest related to file transfer and .NET, not that the original post mentioned .NET in any way shape or form.

[Sending Files in Chunks with MTOM Web Services and .NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/MTOMWebServices.aspx)
By Tim Mackey
*How to send large files across web services in small chunks using MTOM (WSE 3)*

Just note that you need to install *Web Service Enhancements 3.0* (you will find relevant links in the article).

Have an otherwise good day sir!

Answer (score -5):

Well I think it's best to use the TCP protocol. It's reliable and the UDP isn't. While UDP is faster as a best-effort protocol is not "safe". P2P programs use UDP though since it's faster and really don't care that much about package lose. FTP use TCP usually. So I'd suggest to implement TCP and program over sockets. Use a port like 120000 or something because those are free.